# Django. Как правильно создать проект с базой данных MYSQL?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Мне нужно создать проект с базой MYSQL. Когда я создал проект командой `django-admin.py startproject myproject` изменил

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'shop',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'toor',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        "default-character-set":"utf8",            
    }
}
```

И выполнил миграцию оно создало бд sqlite3 и оно как бы не должно. И в папке я создал базу данных находящийся в папке и запущенным сервером. Создавал Valentina Studio 8

Answer (score 0):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME':'shop',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'toor',

    }
}
```

Был правильным